# Making a HTTP Post request with a javascript add-on?

Tags: javascript, html, http, post

What would be the most simplest and effective way of sending an HTTP Post via a Javascript addon?

This javascript add-on would be activated once a visitor clicks a 'Submit' button on a website - and it would need to send across in the POST data what was included in one of the input fields on the website.

I do not want it to get a response. I simply want it to send the HTTP POST request and then disable the button & clear the input field. No response needed.

Since the POST request would be going to an external server - would the website hang/lag until the request was done?

HUGE thank you if anyone can point me in the right direction - or some tips to get this as most effective as possible!

Comment: What do you mean by "add-on"? Are you asking about a Firefox Extension (since Firefox calls those and themes add ons).

Comment: @Quentin - A javascript script which would be attached to the website -- So when a user clicks on a button on the website it would send the post request (with data from an input field on the website). 

Sorry - 'add-on' sounds a little strange. Just a normal javascript script on a website!